# How can I exclude files from one of a multi-root workspace's root folders from search in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is my configuration in .code-workspace:

```
"folders": [
    {
        "path": "."
    },
    {
        "path": "../html/ROOT"
    }
],
```

I'm trying to get all files out of the ROOT folder when I search with ctrl+p (Quick Open).
I can't in any way. This is the last attempt:

```json
"files.exclude": {
    "**/ROOT/**": true
},    
"search.exclude": {
    "**/ROOT/**": true
}
```

I also tried with:

```json
"files.exclude": {
    "**/ROOT": true
},    
"search.exclude": {
    "**/ROOT": true
}
```

and

```json
"files.exclude": {
    "ROOT/**": true
},    
"search.exclude": {
    "ROOT/**": true
}
```

without success.

Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled "`github vscode issues exclude workspace root from search`" and found the following:

- [Multi-Root Workspace: Exclude Subfolders
  #82145 comment #829347865](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82145#issuecomment-829347865) shows that the `files.exclude` setting can be set in a workspace root's `.vscode/settings.json` file.
- [Cannot exclude root folders while searching
  #50638 comment #1554801954](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50638#issuecomment-1554801954) shows that the `search.exclude` setting can be set in a workspace root's `.vscode/settings.json` file.

So, to achieve what you want, you can put the following in the `.vscode/settings.json` of the workspace root folder that you want to exclude from searches:

```json
"search.exclude": {
   "**": true,
}
```